# Paginate don't fill first page? - Laravel 6

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am using the page of Laravel with order by desc and I indicate that 5 elements are displayed.
When returning 7 the first page shows me 2 and the second 5. I want the first one to be filled before the second. If I use ASC it works correctly.

Controller:

```
public function list(){
    $questions = Question::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->paginate(5);
    return view('web.pages.list', compact('questions'));
}
```

Vista:

```
    @foreach ($questions as $q)
        <a href="/list/{{$q->category($q->category_id)}}/{{$q->id}}">
         <div class="container-list-question">
             <div class="header-category-list-question">
               <span>{{$q->category($q->category_id)}}</span>
             </div>
             <div class="data-question">
                 Autor: {{$q->author}}
             </div>
             <div class="title-list-question">
                 <span>{{$q->question}}</span> 
                 <div class="btn-show"> Show question</div>
             </div>
          </div>
        </a>
    @endforeach
{{ $questions->links() }}
```